# Varying choice sets, large data, mnlogit

Tags: r, mlogit, bigdata

I am trying to estimate a multinomial logit model of customer store choice.
There are different choice sets for each customer. The dataset is large, so `mlogit` take too long to converge. `mnlogit` is faster with large data sets, but I can't figure out how to specify that the choice sets vary. Is there an easy fix that I am missing? The dataset is a `mlogit.data` object, and I have set the `chid.var` setting to a choice index variable.

I am not stuck on using `mnlogit`, but it seems like my best option given that I have a large dataset. I can't find any mention of differing choice sets in the `mnlogit` documentation.

Edit:

The warning I get with `mnlogit`:

> In responseMat - Pch :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length